# How to react on "I'm sorry" while accepting the excuse but not willing to say somethign along "not therefor"?

Tags: social-interaction

Lets say some one bumbs into me on the street and excuses for it.
While I'm seeing the excuse as appropiate, a "No Problem" or "Not therefor" or that alike wouldn't be literarly correct, reacting like he became my new liftime archenemy is kinda.... overreacting.

So in what way I can (without appearing rude) express that I was expecting the excuse for it, but as I got it, No hard feelings... ?

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting question! Although it's true that "no problem" is not literally correct, it is one of several very common English-language responses to this sort of mishap. Other standard responses:

"It's okay,"

"Don't worry about it,"

"No worries,"

"It's fine,"

Although somewhat more formal, it would also be correct to reply "Of course!" when somebody says "Excuse me."

As long as you accompany these with the standard physical gestures (such as smiling, nodding, or holding up one's palms) the other person will certainly understand that you are being polite.

Comment: Wow. Thats the perfect fitting term for what I was looking for. Great!

Comment: But for now while this fits for "excuse me" it feels inappropiate for saying it if some one said "I'm sorry" any idea how to react on that wording? Would it be rude by just acepting it via "Okay"?

Comment: @Zaibis - in the event that someone says "I'm sorry", I'm afraid that the correct response would then be some form of "It's all right" rather than "Okay". Although it was not fine for you, English speakers understand that the implication is "You made a mistake which was a nuisance to me, but I am not angry with you." On the other hand, English-language ettiquette understands a response of "Okay" as "I acknowledge but do not accept your apology" - therefore impolite!

Comment: So etiquette forces me to be alright as soon some one excused for it? Thats weired, and makes me feel now like saying "I'm sorry" is unpolite in situations where there is something I'm liable for... unsatisfying.

Comment: I'll leave the question open under that aspect for the case some one has a fit for that. If there is nothing comming up I'll accept your answer tomorrow.

Comment: I understand the conundrum! The best I can offer is that these responses are politenesses whose real meanings are generally understood. Should someone step on my toe, apologize, and receive my response of "It's all right," he understands that he's been an oaf, but that I'm not going to punch him in the face. Anyhow, I hope you find a satisfactory answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I did misunderstand you, so here's a more appropriate answer.

If someone does something that annoys or upsets you and apologises, you could say that it was okay, even if it wasn't.  That's the polite response, even if it is dishonest.  (Certainly it's a very British thing to do and it's something I do without being aware of it)

If, however, you want to be honest rather than polite, then a lot will depend on the circumstances.  You used the example of someone bumping into you and apologising.  You could say:

"Watch where you're going"
"Be careful" or "Be more careful"

Note that you can add "Please" and "Thank you" to make things less confrontational.

> > Original (incorrect) answer below...
> >     First of all, apologies if I've misinterpreted your question.

If I'm reading it correctly, you're asking what response you should give if someone accidentally bumps into you (or something similar).

Well, if that is the case then your initial response of "No problem" is correct.  You could also say something like "That's fine" or "Don't worry about it".

"Not therefore" doesn't translate into English and isn't correct, I've never heard that said or seen it written down before.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks for correcting my wrong vocabulary. But nope thats exactly what I don't want to do. I don't want to say "No problem" (since this obvisious expresses I have no problem with it, what I actually had). Aswell "That's fine" isn't it. Since it wasn't fine for me. Also "Don't worry about it" is soemthing I DONT want to say since it is something he should worry about and try to avoid in future cases. I'm asking for a literal way of expressing There's no need to rack your brain over it. While avoiding anything that expresses "No need for an excuse"